# Inconsistent behavior of UIEdgeInsets.leastNonzeroMagnitude on different iOS simulator architectures

Tags: ios, swift, precision, rosetta-2

I'm encountering an issue where the following code:

```
let minInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: .leastNonzeroMagnitude,
                            left: .leastNonzeroMagnitude,
                            bottom: .leastNonzeroMagnitude,
                            right: .leastNonzeroMagnitude)

print(minInset == .zero)
print(minInset.top.isZero)

// Output
// Rosetta (Intel-based) iOS simulator
// true
// false

// non-Rosetta (ARM-based) iOS simulator
// false
// false
```

Environment:

```
Xcode Version: Xcode 15.3(15E204a)
iOS Target: iOS 17.4
Simulator Architectures: Rosetta (Intel) and non-Rosetta (ARM)
```

I would expect `minInset` to be a non-zero `UIEdgeInsets` value since it's constructed using `.leastNonzeroMagnitude`. However, on the Rosetta simulator, `minInset == .zero` evaluates to `true,` while `minInset.top.isZero` evaluates to `false`, which seems contradictory.

On the non-Rosetta simulator, both expressions evaluate as expected (`false`), indicating that `.leastNonzeroMagnitude` is treated as a non-zero value.

Can someone explain why this behavior differs between the two simulator architectures

I can roughly guess the possible reason, which is the different precision between the two CPU architectures, especially the double precision issue on Intel in the Rosetta environment. However, this still does not explain the contradictory behavior where `minInset == .zero` evaluates to `true`, while `minInset.top.isZero` evaluates to `false`.

Additionally, I'm curious if there are any other pitfalls or potential issues in the Rosetta environment ?

Comment: I am not familiar with what Rosetta is, but on my Intel MacBook, `minInset == .zero` is false.

Comment: well, if you cant reproduce, your can set a breakpoint on `print(minInset == .zero)` in the Rosetta environment, on my m2, it 100% happen